# Is there a way in ag-grid for a custom cell editor to have multiple components?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid custom popup editor.  The popup contains a input field, a datepicker and a select list.  The problem is that each control will prematurely close the popup.

User selects a cell to edit
user selects a value from popup editor
ag-grid closes popup before the user can make entries in the other components

I would like to embed a button for save and one for cancel within my popup editor and have these buttons responsible for closing the popup after the user has had a chance to input data into each popup editor component.  ie user input into the input box, user selects item from select list and user chooses a date from the datepicker.  Then hits save or cancel.

Comment: If possible, can you please post the image of your grid in both cases - when the user is editing the cell [which should show you editor showing all the component which you want to fill before it gets closed] and when the cell is not in the edit mode. Having images will give us an idea of what you are trying to achieve and provide a better solution.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y089Y.png)  You can get an idea of what the grid looks like before clicking on the cell to open the editor, by looking at the cell with the blue 1 in the right hand corner.

Comment: @Don Starkey, Please update the answer if you found the answer that can help readers.